# ExtJS application will not start

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am new to ExtJS (4.1) and now I am trying to make an MVC application work, but there seems to be a bug somewhere. Here is my `app.js`:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});

console.log("out");

Ext.application({
name: 'FI',

controllers:['ListController'],
launch: function() {
    console.log("launch");
   }
});
```

and this is the `ListController`:

```
Ext.define('Fi.controller.ListController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
id: 'installBaseListController',
init: function() {


    console.log("init");
   }
});
```

All the needed js files are loaded properly and no errors are displayed in the console.

However, the only message displayed is `"out"`, meaning that the controller does not get instantiated and the applicationa itself doesn't start. Why?

Comment: I've never used ExtJS before, but is it because you define the application as being named `'FI'` (capital `I`) but the controller on `Fi` (lowercase `i`)?

Comment: Thank you, that was it. Such a childish mistake... Please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: glad that was it! And thanks, I've done so. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application is named `'FI'` (capital `I`) but the controller is on `Fi` (lowercase `i`)!

Answer (score 1):

For future reference:

It also happens when you get any of the related files/classes Ext.define('Xxx.xxx.Xxxx') spelling wrong (case senstive)

Or, any of the launch / init/ initComponent functions spelling wrong (case senstive).